# android sms content provider not giving value in first time

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am working on an Android application. In my app I have to listen the sms and display the the conversation.So I use the following code.

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
     Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
     SmsMessage[] msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
     for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
        sender = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
        message = msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
        smsSummary.append(getContactDisplayNameByNumber(sender, context));
        smsSummary.append(": ").append(message).append("\n");
    }
```

The above code is working fine and I am getting the sms details and content.
So I have to check the convarsation from sms content provider.I used the following code.

```
getConversation(sender,context);

public void getConversation(Context context){
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/");
    Cursor c= context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null ,null,"DATE desc");
//        startManagingCursor(c);
    System.out.println("c.getCount()===="+c.getCount());
    if(c.moveToFirst()){

            for(int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++){
             if(sender.equals(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString())) {

                        body_new=c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();
                        date_new=convertToDate(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date")));
                        num_new=c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString();
                        tid=c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("thread_id"));

                    }

                     c.moveToNext();
             }
    }
    c.close();
}
```

when i get the the first sms from a number .The getConversation() method not listing that number.For example.If I don't have any conversation, I got the first sms from yyyy.The print statement.

```
System.out.println(c.getCount());
```

will return zero.

Like if I have a convarsation from the number xxxx, then i get the first sms from yyyy.the print statement for c.getcount() returns one.That means xxxx info only.

If i get second sms from yyyy.Then it works fine.I will get conversation details of both xxxx and yyyy

Comment: Where are you calling getConversation() method?

Comment: Probably the message isn't written to db when you call getConversation() method. content://mms-sms/ isn't official API and its behaviour can be strange. Try to call getConversation on  some other place.

Comment: @sinisha..thank u..let me try.

Comment: @sinisha.You are right..Please right it on answer section.Then only I can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the message isn't written to db when you call getConversation() method. content://mms-sms/ isn't official API and its behaviour can be strange. Try to call getConversation on some other place